# HTML5 web audio - convert audio buffer into wav file

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I have an audio buffer rendered using `webkitOfflineAudioContext`. Now, I wish to export it into a WAV file. How do I do it? I tried using recorder.js but couldn't figure out how to use it. Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/GBQV8/.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a gist that should help: https://gist.github.com/kevincennis/9754325.

I haven't actually tested this, so there might be a stupid typo or something, but the basic approach will work (I've done it before).

Essentially, you're going to use the web worker from Recorder.js directly so that you can process one big AudioBuffer all in one shot, rather than recording it incrementally in real-time.

I'll paste the code here too, just in case something happens to the gist...

```
// assuming a var named `buffer` exists and is an AudioBuffer instance


// start a new worker 
// we can't use Recorder directly, since it doesn't support what we're trying to do
var worker = new Worker('recorderWorker.js');

// initialize the new worker
worker.postMessage({
  command: 'init',
  config: {sampleRate: 44100}
});

// callback for `exportWAV`
worker.onmessage = function( e ) {
  var blob = e.data;
  // this is would be your WAV blob
};

// send the channel data from our buffer to the worker
worker.postMessage({
  command: 'record',
  buffer: [
    buffer.getChannelData(0), 
    buffer.getChannelData(1)
  ]
});

// ask the worker for a WAV
worker.postMessage({
  command: 'exportWAV',
  type: 'audio/wav'
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked, here is code https://gist.github.com/pramodtech/9760681. It would be great If you can help me understand how to make callback to exportWav in my html page as done in recorder.js //recorder.exportWAV(function(s) { });. Right now I am adding code in worker.onmessage for posting blob to server.

Comment: As you can see, the blob is received in the onmessage event. That event is triggered when the worker sends the completed file, and thus can be used to trigger a callback. You can't use recorder.exportWAV as you do not use the recorder code, only the worker.

Comment: recorderWorker.js is no longer available, but you can find the historical version here: https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/ac0eb8a7c2601fc4ec1cbd1b1ee49f45a6c79580/recorderWorker.js

Comment: Hi @Kevin , Can i convert the audio to 8khz mono wav format from web page ?

Answer (score 7):

I figured I'd share a working solution that I managed to put together from the Kevin's answer.

Here's the `waveWorker.js` script:

```
self.onmessage = function( e ){
  var wavPCM = new WavePCM( e['data']['config'] );
  wavPCM.record( e['data']['pcmArrays'] );
  wavPCM.requestData();
};

var WavePCM = function( config ){
  this.sampleRate = config['sampleRate'] || 48000;
  this.bitDepth = config['bitDepth'] || 16;
  this.recordedBuffers = [];
  this.bytesPerSample = this.bitDepth / 8;
};

WavePCM.prototype.record = function( buffers ){
  this.numberOfChannels = this.numberOfChannels || buffers.length;
  var bufferLength = buffers[0].length;
  var reducedData = new Uint8Array( bufferLength * this.numberOfChannels * this.bytesPerSample );

  // Interleave
  for ( var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++ ) {
    for ( var channel = 0; channel < this.numberOfChannels; channel++ ) {

      var outputIndex = ( i * this.numberOfChannels + channel ) * this.bytesPerSample;
      var sample = buffers[ channel ][ i ];

      // Check for clipping
      if ( sample > 1 ) {
        sample = 1;
      }

      else if ( sample < -1 ) {
        sample = -1;
      }

      // bit reduce and convert to uInt
      switch ( this.bytesPerSample ) {
        case 4:
          sample = sample * 2147483648;
          reducedData[ outputIndex ] = sample;
          reducedData[ outputIndex + 1 ] = sample >> 8;
          reducedData[ outputIndex + 2 ] = sample >> 16;
          reducedData[ outputIndex + 3 ] = sample >> 24;
          break;

        case 3:
          sample = sample * 8388608;
          reducedData[ outputIndex ] = sample;
          reducedData[ outputIndex + 1 ] = sample >> 8;
          reducedData[ outputIndex + 2 ] = sample >> 16;
          break;

        case 2:
          sample = sample * 32768;
          reducedData[ outputIndex ] = sample;
          reducedData[ outputIndex + 1 ] = sample >> 8;
          break;

        case 1:
          reducedData[ outputIndex ] = ( sample + 1 ) * 128;
          break;

        default:
          throw "Only 8, 16, 24 and 32 bits per sample are supported";
      }
    }
  }

  this.recordedBuffers.push( reducedData );
};

WavePCM.prototype.requestData = function(){
  var bufferLength = this.recordedBuffers[0].length;
  var dataLength = this.recordedBuffers.length * bufferLength;
  var headerLength = 44;
  var wav = new Uint8Array( headerLength + dataLength );
  var view = new DataView( wav.buffer );

  view.setUint32( 0, 1380533830, false ); // RIFF identifier 'RIFF'
  view.setUint32( 4, 36 + dataLength, true ); // file length minus RIFF identifier length and file description length
  view.setUint32( 8, 1463899717, false ); // RIFF type 'WAVE'
  view.setUint32( 12, 1718449184, false ); // format chunk identifier 'fmt '
  view.setUint32( 16, 16, true ); // format chunk length
  view.setUint16( 20, 1, true ); // sample format (raw)
  view.setUint16( 22, this.numberOfChannels, true ); // channel count
  view.setUint32( 24, this.sampleRate, true ); // sample rate
  view.setUint32( 28, this.sampleRate * this.bytesPerSample * this.numberOfChannels, true ); // byte rate (sample rate * block align)
  view.setUint16( 32, this.bytesPerSample * this.numberOfChannels, true ); // block align (channel count * bytes per sample)
  view.setUint16( 34, this.bitDepth, true ); // bits per sample
  view.setUint32( 36, 1684108385, false); // data chunk identifier 'data'
  view.setUint32( 40, dataLength, true ); // data chunk length

  for (var i = 0; i < this.recordedBuffers.length; i++ ) {
    wav.set( this.recordedBuffers[i], i * bufferLength + headerLength );
  }

  self.postMessage( wav, [wav.buffer] );
  self.close();
};
```

And here's how you can use it:

```
async function audioBufferToWaveBlob(audioBuffer) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var worker = new Worker('./waveWorker.js');

    worker.onmessage = function( e ) {
      var blob = new Blob([e.data.buffer], {type:"audio/wav"});
      resolve(blob);
    };

    let pcmArrays = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < audioBuffer.numberOfChannels; i++) {
      pcmArrays.push(audioBuffer.getChannelData(i));
    }

    worker.postMessage({
      pcmArrays,
      config: {sampleRate: audioBuffer.sampleRate}
    });

  });

}
```

It's pretty quickly hacked together so feel free (of course) to fix it up and post a link to a better version in the comments :)

Comment: This has noticeable clipping because the allowed range for 16 bit data is [-32768, 32767], similarly 24bit and 32bit.

It can be fixed with something like this:

```
          if ( sample > 0 ) {
            sample = sample * 32767;
          } else {
            sample = sample * 32768;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

For no real time processing, take a look at [OfflineAudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext).

That might be useful to process audio data as if it was a regular AudioContext, but not in real time. If your data does not com from the microphone, you probably want to want to process it as fast as possible. Then, you'll need OfflineAudioContext to create a buffer before encoding it to wav

Comment: Can someone elaborate, why this answer - that seems very promising - has been downvoted? It seems to be available in Firefox as well as Webkit (iOS9+). Looks much better than deprecated webWorkers!

Answer (score 0):

When using recorder.js, make sure you start with recording a piece of audio, and then stop it. After you stopped the recorder you can call the `.exportWAV` function. The callback contains a blob in wav format. Instead of recording the buffer yourself, you'd better use recorder.js's buffer creation, because if you call exportWAV, it will export the buffer it previously saved. It created the buffer from the source object you entered when creating a new recorder.

```
var rec = new Recorder(yourSourceObject);
rec.record();
//let it record
rec.stop();
rec.exportWAV(function(blob){
    //the generated blob contains the wav file
}])
```

You can also check out the source code of [recorderWorker.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/recorderWorker.js) and find out how to convert a buffer to a wav file yourself.

Comment: I don't want real time processing because if audio is 4 mins long then user have to wait for 4 mins. So I choose offline processing. I did check recorderWorker.js but no success yet.

Comment: I might try to make something similar when I get back... Hopefully within a couple hours. I have tried using things from the recorder a while ago, so I might still know a bit of it.

Comment: Thanks MarijnS95!! appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know if I can finish the code now, but I would already suggest you to use the code as a worker. Workers are background tasks, independent of the browser frame (that is also how the recorder itself works). This means you will get no lagg on the webpage because of converting.

Comment: Oh, one other question: are you going to use mono or stereo audio??

Comment: Besides that, could you post some working code? The code in the jsfiddle is missing some parts.