# Convert a BLOB file (a music file) to .WAV in NODE.js (server-side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I'm struggling with a seemingly simple concept.

I have a Node server it properly receives a POST request.
I am posting a Blob to it (converting the blob to a .wav file).

What do I need to do to save this Blob to disk as a .wav file?
I am using a music player to play the user's uploaded music file and then it is supposed to play the song.

Comment: What have you tried?  You collect the uploaded data (how you do this depends on implementation, are you building your own HTTP server or using Express, etc.) and write it to disk (either by collecting payload first, or preferably by streaming out).

Comment: Everything is done except the saving to disk - I am using HTML5 to capture sound, and then posting the Blob to an Express 4 server. I just need to know how to go from Blob -> .wav file on disk.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give too much information but are you using Express? and which database would you like to store that on.

You may want to

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
    var cors = require('cors');

    var db = new sqlite3.Database("db/database.db");
    var app = express();

    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: false }));

    app.use(express.static('public'));
function toArrayBuffer(buffer) {
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
        view[i] = buffer[i];
    }
    return ab;
}


  app.post("/blobs" function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
//You should hopefully have your blob show up...
    toArray(blob);
    db.run("INSERT INTO pics (name, blob) VALUES (?, ?)",___nameOfBlob(hopefully from req.body as well if you have a form___, __bufferBase64__, function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Give us more details if that doesn't work in general...
If you want to convert to a .wav
Check this out:

```
function encodeWAV(samples) {
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
var view = new DataView(buffer);

writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
view.setUint32(4, 32 + samples.length * 2, true);
writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
view.setUint16(22, 2, true);
view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
writeString(view, 36, 'data');
view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

return view;
}
function exportWAV(type) {
var bufferL = mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength);
var bufferR = mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength);
var interleaved = interleave(bufferL, bufferR);
var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], {
    type: type
});

this.postMessage(audioBlob);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm working with sounds, not images, as mentiond. Also, I'm not trying to put the sound into a DB, I'm trying to save it to disk so I can play it using a media player.

Comment: That isn't relevant at all. I'm just trying figure out, in Node.js, how to save a Blob containing .wav file information to an actual .wav file on my filesystem.

Comment: Hey Charles, ok relax so If I were you I'd edit the question to how do I convert a blob to a wave file or add that to the description...

Comment: Thanks for you input. If you notice in the original question, it states "What do I need to do to save this Blob to disk as a .wav file?"

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560413/html5-web-audio-convert-audio-buffer-into-wav-file

Comment: How did any of those solutions work? Did anything happen or was it a complete waste of time?

Comment: That's actually a java bit of code which I got from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560413/html5-web-audio-convert-audio-buffer-into-wav-file I think its to get more of an idea