# How to download speech (audio) created from text using Text-to-speech responsivevoice.js?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, responsivevoice

I'm using [responsivevoice.js](http://responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/responsivevoice.js) JavaScript library to listen to articles online. It's the best free Text-to-speech I found, better then lots of paid ones I tried, but I need to download the audio as well and I have no idea on how to do that. Any ideas on how could I do that ? Or is there any other good Text-to-speech, with unlimited characters and download capabilities ?

I made a [quick demo](http://texttoaudio.meteor.com) to better illustrate the situation.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Have a look here, is this sort of what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560413/html5-web-audio-convert-audio-buffer-into-wav-file

Comment: Thanks, seems really interesting. Going to dig into it..

Answer (score 4):

Use URL like: `http://responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/getvoice.php?t=Type%20text%20here&tl=en-US`

This is the URL `responsivevoice.js` used to read text.
Replace `Type%20text%20here` with your own text.

```
<a href="javascript:var text=escape(prompt('Type text here: '));
window.location.href = 'http://responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/getvoice.php?t='+ text +'&tl=en-US';" id="a">Play</a>
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/017mfce0/

Comment: The license terms for this solution are quite unclear and by accessing the fallback voice generator in that way, anyone is in risk of being blocked by responsivevoice.org. Also, I am assuming that the audio files are generated by a fallback backend (the link is pointing to a php script, so probably no client side JS involved).