# Web Audio API downloading encoded audio

Tags: download, save, export, web-audio-api

I am trying to decode an audio file, apply an effect, then encode it again to .WAV format so the user can save the file back to their computer.

At the moment when I press the "Play" button the sound plays as it should, but no download box is popping up, for the user to download the encoded file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <title>offlineAudioContext example</title>

    <script src="recorder.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <button class="play">Play</button>

   <script>

// define online and offline audio context

var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var offlineCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(2,44100*10,44100);

// define variables

var myScript = document.querySelector('script');
var play = document.querySelector('.play');
var stop = document.querySelector('.stop');


// decodeAudioData to decode audio then create buffer


    function getData() {

        request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('GET', 'kick.mp3', true);

        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';


        request.onload = function() {

        var audioData = request.response;

        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {

        var source = offlineCtx.createBufferSource();

        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(offlineCtx.destination);
        source.start();
      //source.loop = true;

        offlineCtx.startRendering().then(function(renderedBuffer) {
        console.log('Rendering completed successfully');
        var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(); 
        var song = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
        song.buffer = renderedBuffer;

        song.connect(audioCtx.destination);

        play.onclick = function() {

            song.start(0);
            sendWaveToPost(renderedBuffer);

        }

    function sendWaveToPost(buffer) {
        var worker = new Worker('recorderWorker.js');

        // initialize the new worker
        worker.postMessage({
        command: 'init',
        config: {
        sampleRate: 44100

    }
  });


  // callback for `exportWAV`


  // send the channel data from our buffer to the worker
    worker.postMessage({
        command: 'record',
        buffer: [
            buffer.getChannelData(0),
            buffer.getChannelData(1)
        ]
});

  // ask the worker for a WAV
    worker.postMessage({
        command: 'exportWAV',
        type: 'audio/wav'

    });

        worker.onmessage = function(e) {

        Recorder.forceDownload(e.data, 'SomeFileName.wav');
  };

}       


      }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Rendering failed: ' + err);
          // Note: The promise should reject when startRendering is called a second time on an OfflineAudioContext
      });
    });
  }

  request.send();

}

// Run getData to start the process off

getData();


  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

I know it is probably something very simple, it often is with me I always ending up missing a small detail!

Various sources have been used including another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560413/html5-web-audio-convert-audio-buffer-into-wav-file) and [MDN example](http://mdn.github.io/offline-audio-context-promise/)

So thank you beforehand for any answers, and those who have already contributed to expanding understanding and awareness of this topic.